# How to draw an imageButton with a with this background

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am trying to draw this shape in `xml` and I was hoping to just do it on an `ImageButton` this what I have

```
<ImageButton
     android:layout_width="48dp"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
     android:alpha="0.14"
     android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
     android:background="@drawable/round_background"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_location"
```

Comment: what do you mean by "without overriding the layout"  ?

Comment: it says override since the min api does not support it

Comment: did you mean         `android:foreground=""` ?

Comment: yes, I don't want to use that I want to use the src and background maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the attributs `android:foreground` on **API 23** and lower you can create a style like below :

```
 <style name="MyImageButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton">
        <item name="android:foreground">@drawable/round_background</item>
    </style>
```

and just you need is to apply this style in your ImageButton :

```
 <ImageButton
     style="@style/MyImageButton"
     android:layout_width="48dp"
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
     android:alpha="0.14"
     android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"/>
```

Comment: how about the icon, @drawable/ic_location

Comment: Or rather what would be the best way to achieve that image?

Comment: you can add it in your round_background by using `layer-list`

Comment: i have a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66497608/7085389) please check it

Comment: @Maria The best way if I was in your place I use MaterailButton chek this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58529735/7085389)